# How can I aggregate int column to array<int> in flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am exploring a way to achive this like the SQL below in flink.

```
SELECT a_tag,NEST(type) AS type_arr FROM a GROUP BY a_tag
```

`NEST()` is a `user defined function` whitch aggregate `int` to `array<int>`.

But i can't change the output type because the UDF class extends `AggregateFunction`

Is there any suggestion?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink has provided a built-in aggregation function called `collect()` whitch can handle this situation.

Note that the result type of `collect()` will be `MULTISET`